# What should I create instead of Bootstrapper? Prism 6.1.0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I've tried to update my application from Prism v4.0 to Prism v6.1.0 and run package manager:
PM> Install-Package Prism.Core

and PM has installed such packages:

- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll

The next step I've tried to create bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType<IShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>();
    }     
    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(StackPanel), Container.Resolve<StackPanelRegionAdapter>());
        return mappings;
    } 
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();            
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleBModule));
        return catalog;
    }
}
```

and I've tried to resolve the `UnityBootstrapper`. However, there is no such a class at Prism 6.1.0.
So I've tried to install by Nuget:

```
Prism.UnityExtesions
```

However NuGet says: `This package is no longer supported. Please use the new Prism.Unity package`.

There is a bootstrapper class with Prism 5.0. But Prism 5.0 is not supported now. For example, in this example [HelloWorld](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-Code-54758014/view/Reviews) from code.msdn.

So to my mind come the question: **How to create bootstrapper at Prism 6.1.0?**

Comment: `Please use the new Prism.Unity package`

Comment: @Jehof yeah, I've installed the package. However, I cannot inherits UnityBootstapper as there is no such class in Prism.Unity

Comment: Try clean your references first, delete  all reference of Microsoft.Practices.xxx and prism, then to install Prism 6, run the following command in the Package Manager Console: 
**PM> Install-Package Prism.Core**, and to  install Unity for Prism 6 run the command : **PM>Install-Package Prism.Unity**

Comment: @Jehof, thanks! It is really dummy that I can make such mistakes). Jehof, please post your answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @toumir, first uninstall all `Microsoft.Practices.*` packages (check your packages.config to be sure they're all uninstalled).

Since you're trying to use Unity with Prism 6, the **only** package you have to install is [Prism.Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Unity/). This will automatically bring in all other packages needed:

- Unity
- CommonServiceLocator
- Prism.Wpf

  - Prism.Core

It's a good practice to only add the most specific package, as with the new project files (.NET Core, ASP.NET 5, Win10 UWP) the old packages.config file is replaced by a project.json file and NuGet v3 will take care of [better dependency resolving](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/ProjectJson-Dependency). As of today it's not used yet for WPF, but that shouldn't keep you from doing it "right".

For new [documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Documentation/WPF) and [samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf) on Prism 6, please head over to the Prism GitHub repositories.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! If I could upvote your answer more than once, I would do it! Million thanks:)!

Comment: As time passes, this answer has become obsolete as well :-(. the "new" method is to use `PrismApplication` (Prism 7+) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47910554/426315