# How to implement the new PrismApplication to replace the Bootstrapper class

Tags: prism

Since the `Bootstrapper` Class is obsolete with Prism 7 I would like to change my C# WPF App using the `PrismApplication` Class.

Does anybody know how to refactor a Prism 6 App using the `Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper` to the new `PrismApplication`?

I´m asking because the documentation regarding those pre-releases is pretty limited and I am not the best in understanding what I need to do from just looking at the Prism source code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on what your bootstrapper does, but `Prism.Unity.PrismApplication` has similar methods to override, so you should be able to copy the code over from the bootstrapper. Probably you only need `RegisterTypes` and `CreateShell`. Remember to update `App.xaml` to change the type of your application...

`App.xaml` should be something like this:

```
<prism:PrismApplication x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
                        x:ClassModifier="internal" 
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"/>
```

and for completeness' sake, `App.xaml.cs`:

```
internal partial class App
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but the `ConfigureModuleCatalog()`doesnt seem to be there / is no longer overwriteable. How should I register my modules now?

Comment: See line 203 here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs: `protected virtual void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog) { }`

Comment: *Remember to update `App.xaml` to change the type of your application...* what do you mean by this? What would need to be changed?

Comment: The app's base type is defined there, and by default it's `System.Windows.Application`. Here, we want it to be `Prism.Unity.PrismApplication`...

Comment: Well, you´ve opend my eyes. I´ve had a classic _copy & paste_ error. I copied the `ConfigureModuleCatalog` from the old `Bootstrapper` class without noticing the new `PrismApplication ConfigureModuleCatalog` needs to have a parameter of `IModuleCatalog` passed in.

Comment: My issue was that I didn't update the tag from <Application> to <prism:PrismApplication>

Answer (score 11):

I started with sample 1 of the [Prism samples on GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf) and immediately I get a warning that using a `UnityBootstrapper` is deprecated. So I sought to upgrade it to the current mechanism.

First step is to replace the base class of your application from `Application` to `PrismApplication` in `App.xaml`. It should now look like this;

```xml
<unity:PrismApplication x:Class="BootstrapperShell.App"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BootstrapperShell" 
                        xmlns:unity="http://prismlibrary.com/">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</unity:PrismApplication>
```

Then in `App.xaml.cs`, remove the reference to `Application` and implement the abstract methods of `PrismApplication`. Copy across the contents of `InitializeShell` in `Bootstrapper.cs` into the `CreateShell()` method. The final result should look like this;

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
    }
}
```

I also added some markup to `MainWindow.xaml` in order to ensure that it was resolving correctly;

```xml
<Window x:Class="BootstrapperShell.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Shell" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="24">Hello</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Everything should work as it did before.

Comment: Can you expand on why the app needs to be public? Normally, one tries to keep the surface of one's assemblies as small as possible...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, So call me dumb or whatever but I had the same issue with the same error:

> App.RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistery): no suitable method found to override

My issue was that I went and copied and pasted the `App.xaml` from [Here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/02-Regions/Regions/App.xaml) and the cs from [Here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/02-Regions/Regions/App.xaml.cs) and didnt change the name space in the `App.xaml` from `x:Class="Regions.App"` to `x:Class="WpfApp.App"`

Comment: Got same issue, i restarted visual studio it worked fine later